# SwiftでUIViewの縦・横画面のレイアウトでAmbiguos Layoutを出さないようにする方法

Tags: swift

Swiftプログラムをしていてwarningも気になり思わず質問させてください。
storyboardでUIViewをレイアウトしていてConstraintsを使って配置しています。
そのUIViewを横画面にした際にUIViewの位置やサイズを変更したいと思っています。
しかし、Constraintsを指定するとframeなどで位置・サイズ指定しても変わりません。
そのためConstraintsを削除してプログラムで指定してあげるのですが、Ambiguos Layoutのwarningが発生します。
位置が特定されていないからです。

このような場合、熟達者の皆さんはどのようにプログラムしているのでしょうか？
1. Ambiguos Layoutのwarningなんか気にしない
2. warningは発生させなく、プログラムで操作する何かがある。

私は2を期待して投稿しています。ご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 0):

横画面用のレイアウトを満たす制約を設定すれば良いだけです。
私が最近実装したケースでは、縦画面用の NSLayoutConstraint と横画面用の NSLayoutConstraint をそれぞれ配列にもっておき、画面の向きが変わった際にそれぞれの `isActive` プロパティを `true` / `false` に設定するようにしました。

**追記**
サンプルコードを以下に示します。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var portraitConstaints:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var landscapeConstaints:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let subview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(subview)
        subview.backgroundColor = .blue

        // 縦横共通の制約
        subview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true

        // 縦画面の制約（画面の上半分にsubviewを配置）
        portraitConstaints = [
            subview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor),
            subview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)
        ]

        // 横画面の制約（画面の左半分にsubviewを配置）
        landscapeConstaints = [
            subview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            subview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ]

        // 初期状態はとりあえず縦画面の制約を有効にしておく（横画面で起動される場合は要修正）
        portraitConstaints.forEach { (cons) in
            cons.isActive = true
        }
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        let portrait = size.height > size.width

        portraitConstaints.forEach { (cons) in
            cons.isActive = portrait
        }
        landscapeConstaints.forEach { (cons) in
            cons.isActive = !portrait
        }

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (_) in
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: > isActive プロパティを true / false に設定  
とはどのような使い方でしょうか？参考になるURLページなどがありましたら教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: サンプルコードを追記しました。ご参考に。コードでNSLayoutConstaintを生成する方法は色々ありますので、NSLayoutAnchorを使う方法でなくても構いません。初期状態のNSLayoutConstaintはStoryboard上で設定して、IBOutletやIBOutletCollectionで持っておいてもOKです。

Comment: NSLayoutAnchorの使い方は https://qiita.com/yucovin/items/4bebcc7a8b1088b374c9 などが参考になります